# windows form アプリを配布できる形にしたい

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

提示画像ですがbinディレクトリの.exeがあるディレクトリです。タイトル通りなのですが作ったソフトを配布する場合リリーズビルドにしてビルドすると思いますがそのほかにしないといけない設定等ありますでしょうか？
調べましたが古い情報しかし出てこなくてどれも参考になりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 知りたいこと

visual studio 2022 を使ってwindows form app を配布できる形にする方法が知りたい。

#### 知っていること

リリーズビルドにする

#### 試したこと

参考サイトを参考にしましたがVSのバージョンが古くて参考になりません。

参考サイト
https://fsbblog.jp/archive/entry-106.html
https://leadtools.zendesk.com/hc/ja/articles/4407780954137-%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E9%85%8D%E5%B8%83%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95
https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/fdotnet/chushin/introwinform_12/introwinform_12_01.html

###### 環境

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2022
windows form app
.NET 6.0

Comment: フレームワークが.NET5以降と.NET Frameworkで変わるので、それも記載してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft公式のドキュメントに記載があります。
VisualStudioの画像が英語になってますが、雰囲気は大体伝わるんじゃないかと。

[単一ファイルの配置と実行可能ファイル](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs)